# Oracle Unique constraint violated ORA-00001 without duplicate values

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table that uses a sequence and also has an index defined on it. The error is on the index and I cant find any duplicate values in my table for the combination of the five columns on which the index is defined. I have tried the following things:

1. I thoroughly checked for duplicate values for which index is violated
2. Match the max(sequence) with the sequence's next value.
3. Rebuild the index in case if it is corrupt.
4. There are also no triggers defined on this table.

All of these are in place but I am still facing the error.Please help regarding what else can I try!!

Comment: What action are you trying to do when you get this error?  Create the index or insert data?

Comment: I am trying to insert the data which, when I tried to add manually, was added successfully. But I cannot do that for each value that fails as the number is quite big.

Comment: Is is possible that you have misunderstood how the sequence works and that the "next" value is colliding with one of your data items?  Otherwise, add the create table statement (at least the bits that define index and associated fields) to the question above.  Also describe how you are taking the data and doing the insert as the problem could be buffering etc.

Comment: There is a procedure that is called which has insert statement causing the problem. Also I will be grateful if you can explain how buffering can cause the problem as it seems probable. because when I try to insert a single value manually it gives me no error.

Comment: "There is a procedure ..." Did you call the procedure when you inserted manually?  Is it a built in procedure or did you write it.  If you wrote the procedure, put it in the question so people can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to insert a row into a table with a e key that is already present in the table. Why no do a select on the table, using the values of the key columns that you are trying to insert and verify that this is indeed the case?

Comment: I tried doing that. There are no values in the table for which the insertion is failing( giving unique constraint violation error)

Comment: @Shivanispv Can you share the exact code you are running that gives the problem, and also the statement that works?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not permitted to do so but I can tell you that it is a simple insert query which is run by a windows service. The statement that works is also the same insert query which is run manually.

Comment: @Shivanispv. Can you reproduce the problem with a simple example using, for example, the standard EMP table in the SCOTT schema?

Comment: insert into SCOTT.EMP(emp_id,name,dept,application_working_on,role,doj) values (emp_seq.nextval,'xyz','IS','Some_application','DBA',to_date('1-5-1981‌​','dd-mm-yyyy'))   Say i have a unique index defined on dept, application_working_on and role considering every application has just one employee with a certain role.

Comment: Also the problem lies on index itself and not the sequence as when I dropped the index there are no more errors occurring.

Comment: So how is that reproducing the problem? What I am looking for is a small piece of code that I can run that will reproduce the error.

Comment: The line where the error is occurring is an insert query like the one I have written above. I am not sure if it will be possible for you to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What I am seeking is the probable conditions in which the unique constraint of a unique index be violated.

Comment: @Shivanispv   The most probable condition is that you have done something wrong! That may sound sarcastic, but unless you can show otherwise, that is the case. I would try and construct a reproducible case; you may find that the process of doing that will show you your error.

Comment: Its most certainly something wrong I have done. I will just dig deeper. But Thanks for all the help :)